# Unable to find an installation of R on the system; Unable to locate R binary by scanning standard locations

Tags: r, redhat, rstudio-server

I installed R on redhat using the following commands:

- /configure --enable-R-shlib –with-readline=no –with-x=no
- make clean
- make
- make install

I have the R_HOME installed in /local/home/UserX/R-3.2.3. So I added it to the Path **(#echo $PATH : /local/home/UserX/R-3.2.3/bin/:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin).**

After installing Rstudio Server, when I execute sudo rstudio-server verify-installation. I got :

**Unable to find an installation of R on the system (which R didn't return valid output); Unable to locate R binary by scanning standard locations

rstudio-server start/running, process 13900**

1. which R : **/local/home/UserX/R-3.2.3/bin/R**
2. ls -la /usr/bin/R : **ls: cannot access /usr/bin/R: No such file or directory**
3. ls -la /usr/local/bin/R : **ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/R: No such file or directory**
4. ls -la /opt/local/bin/R : **ls: cannot access /opt/local/bin/R: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 2):

---

1) R is in the EPEL repo https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL , R-3.3.0 . ... 18 packages are available ... https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/r/ ... # `yum install R-core R-core-devel`

2) Or use *your R* : Add the PATH → `export PATH=/local/home/UserX/R-3.2.3/bin:$PATH` , .... where $PATH will do for /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin .... etc. default.

---

Note : .bin/:/sbin is a syntax error in your "PATH try".

---

Comment: I've already added the R_Home to the path but didn't work. Are you sure that R-3.3.0 is not for educational purpose for the moment ? Shall I download R.x86_64, R-core.x86_64, R-core-devel.x86_64, R-devel.x86_64,  R-java.x86_64, • R-java-devel.x86_64 from your second link and then execute yum install R-* ? I have RHEL 6.7      so maybe this link is more suitable for my version :   https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that a normal user can't access to the R_Home, because it was installed under a home directory of a sudoer user. I reinstalled R on another directory where any user can access to it and that solved my problem.